# Distance/Speed word problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A train of length 300m can cross a pole in 8 seconds. How long will it take to cross a platform of length 600m.

I can't seem to appreciate the very beginning. Crossing the pole implies that the time from the point the nose of the train crosses the start of the pole to when the end of the train crosses the end of the pole.

(train) --------    In this case, I can see that in crossing the pole a distance of 300m is covered??

I don't get anything about this question, even picturing the physical events regarding the train.

Can someone hint me on the required though process?

Cheers

Comment: Draw a diagram.  First draw it at the moment where the front of the train is even with the start of the platform.  Then draw a second diagram where the tail of the train is even with the end of the platform.  How far has the front of the train traveled between the two figures?

Comment: @turkeyhundt Well considering the pole, at the start the distance covered is 0m. But we dont know the length of the pole so we cant say the distance covered??

Comment: The pole is just an example set up to show you how long it takes the train to travel it's own length (8s).  So basically to get the answer, the train has to travel it's own length plus 600 more meters.  For a total of 900m.  ETA: the pole has no length.  It can be considered a point.

Answer (score 2):

The train takes 8 seconds to cross the pole, which means it takes 8 seconds to travel 300 meters.

In the second case, time starts when the front of the train is at the front of the platform. Time stops not when the front of the train reaches the end of the platform (600 meters), but when the *back* of the train clears the *end* of the platform. That's 300 m more, or 900 meters total.

Three increments of 300 m is 3 sets of 8 seconds, or 24 sec.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

If you want to tackle this problem from the calculus side of view:

S = distance

$\frac{ds}{dt} = 75/2 = velocity$

This was found from:
Distance traveled over time ($\frac{ds}{dt}$, which is velocity) was 300m over 8 seconds: $\frac{300}{8} = \frac{75}{2}$

Integrate to get s(t) and try from there (assuming when time, t, is 0 distance traveled is 0).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it is obvious that the train's velocity is $\frac{300 m}{8 sec}$. If the pole were situated at the very beginning of the platform and then every 300 m, it would require the same 8 seconds to pass the first pole. Add to that the time for the entire train to traverse each additional pole ON the platform, which would be an ADDITIONAL two 300 m lengths, what would that make the total time?

Comment: I've been thinking all along, that "pole" refered to a horizontal metal stick as opposed to a vertical pole.